# How does a debugger work? In other words how do programs which share the Address space of another program work?

Tags: debugging

How does a debugger work? In other words how do programs which share the Address space of another program work? How will they have ability to write on to another process' address space?

Comment: You'll find a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216819/how-does-a-debugger-work

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216819/how-does-a-debugger-work

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question will vary per operating system. I'll just quickly orient you towards the appropriate documentation for the Win32 platform. The short answer is that they don't, instead there is a win32 api for this sort of work.

The main article on the subject is listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809754.aspx).