# Should clang and gcc produce a diagnostic message when a program does pointer arithmetic on a function pointer?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

This program compiles without errors, for example with `clang -Wall -std=c11 a.c` and `gcc -Wall -std=c11 a.c`. Is this a bug in clang and gcc? Because arithmetic is not defined on pointers to function types.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(void) {}

int main(void){
    void (*p)(void) = f;
    printf("%p\n", p);
    printf("%p\n", p + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

There's a constraint on addition that either both operands have arithmetic type, or one is a pointer to a complete object type. I believe `p` is a pointer to a function type, not a a pointer to any sort of object type. Here's the C11 standard:

> 6.5.6 Additive operators
>
> Constraints
>
> 2. For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a
>      pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer
>      type. (Incrementing is equivalent to adding 1.)

Conforming compilers are required to produce a diagnostic message if any translation unit violates a constraint. Again, the C11 standard:

> 5.1.1.3 Diagnostics
>
> 1. A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined
>      manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit
>      contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the
>      behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or
>      implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be produced in
>      other circumstances.

Comment: To invoke standards compliance you need `-std=c11 -pedantic` (for gcc and clang)

Comment: @pmg thanks, can you make this an answer?

Comment: You could have an array of pointers to functions, though.

Comment: BTW, `%p` is the wrong format specifier. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932910/how-to-print-the-address-of-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function pointer arithmetic is a [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html) also implemented by clang.

To invoke standards compliance you need

```
gcc -std=c11 -pedantic ...
clang -std=c11 -pedantic ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the `-Wpointer-arith` flag to produce warnings

```
a.c:8:22: warning: arithmetic on a pointer to the function type 'void (void)' is a GNU extension [-Wpointer-arith]
    printf("%p\n", p + 1);
                   ~ ^
```

From GNU [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html)

> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on
>   pointers to void and on pointers to functions. This is done by
>   treating the size of a void or of a function as 1.

Clang [-Wpointer-arith](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wpointer-arith) documentation

> warning: arithmetic on a pointer to the function type B is a GNU extension