# Low level details of debuggers on windows, linux, OSX

Tags: debugging, systems-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does a debugger work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216819/how-does-a-debugger-work)

I'm trying to learn more about debuggers. I know the basics of debugging in general and some low level details on windows. But I would like to learn more about the details of how debugging is implemented. Like hardware and software interrupts on windows, linux, OSX and how can a debugger be attached to a running process, and so on.

I am not asking for an answer. All I'd like to get from you is some papers, books, links where I could learn more about this topic.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nobody posted an answer I'll just post what I found in case someone else will need it.

I strongly suggest the book "How Debuggers Work: Algorithms, Data Structures, and Architecture" ( Jonathan B. Rosenberg, [description](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471149667,descCd-description.html) ).

There is also a great paper on implementing a debugger "A Survey of Support For Implementing Debuggers" ([paper](http://www.icir.org/vern/papers/debug-support.pdf)).

There are also some blogs and more detailed papers, but these two really helped me out.