# When debugging, is the app built?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does a debugger work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216819/how-does-a-debugger-work)

When I use debug, how does it look inside? The app is compiled and build or there some runtine compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app is compiled as usual and debugging symbols are generated. There's also the usual Just-In-Time compilation which is not unique to debugging.

Answer (score 1):

It is built with the addition of [PDB files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that allow for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

going deep inside debug is just a config type in [MSBUILD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx)
whatever you have in `MSBUILD` in the `DEBUG` section would be done