# How Can I Attach a Remote Debugger to a .Net 4.5 WCF Service without Blocking Other Incoming Requests?

Tags: wcf, remote-debugging

I'd like to attach a debugger to a WCF service without interrupting incoming requests which are not the one I intend to debug. I thought I could use a conditional break point to only break on specific conditions in the request coming from my machine. I used SoapUI to send the request with the specific conditions. When that break point was hit, I opened a different request in SoapUI, but that request was not processed until I released my break. My goal was to see if I could attach a remote debugger to a production server without interrupting other requests. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You kinda answered your own question based on the behavior you describe. Breakpoints seem to cause a process to "pause" not just the thread executing the code that contains the breakpoint. There is a capability to attach multiple remote debugging sessions to a process but this doesn't necessarily imply the process is executing other threads as normally.

Comment: Ooops, I forgot to add "How" to my question.

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21746853/9711) for details on how debugging is implemented internally by the hardware. Once you hit a breakpoint, game over, the process goes into step mode.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.