# Explanation of attach to process in PyCharm?

Tags: debugging, pycharm, attach-to-process

What is going on in the background in PyCharm whenever you run [these PyCharm instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/attaching-to-local-process.html) to "attach to a local process", that makes it possible to then set breakpoints and debug. (A Chalice/Flask app lets say...)

Answer (score 0):

Often the PyCharm debugger [pydev.py](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py) will be launched first and [spawn the process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_(computing)) that runs the code you want to debug.

When an application/process is launched separately *"Attach to Process"* means the debugger process will be launched in parallel and be attached to an already running process that the debugger did not spawn (like Chalice/Flask or other applications that use their own spawning process).

Comment: what is the process of "attaching" look like?  is it wrapping the process somehow?  re-launching the process?

Comment: @Back2Basics it uses an [OS-level API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216837) so it depends on the OS you're using. The whole point of using the IDE's interface is making those specifics transparent and a non-concern for the developer.